# give access with spring security in xml file for one user

Tags: java, xml, spring-security, waffle

I was using waffle and spring security 3.2 to set access to jsf2 pages.
I used this [example](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Docs/spring/SpringSecuritySingleSignOnFilter.md)

Everything works fine, but I am curious, if posible to set access to page via xml file for one user???
Something like that:

```
 <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="PRINCIPAL='tom'" />
```

I couldn't find answer in internet

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you use SpEL expressions:

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true">
    ....
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="principal.name=='tom'" />
    ....
</sec:http>
```

Comment: You are welcome. @Darka, I've seen your edit for my answer that was rejected. You can post `authentication.name` way as a separate answer and accept it.

Comment: thanks again, but I wlll leave your answer. I think it depends from configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Maksym answer I found my solution (I think in some cases both can be right) :

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true">
    ....
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authentication.name=='tom'" />
    ....
</sec:http>
```